# Rent A Virtual Machine

Tags: windows, virtual-machines, geolocation

I'm looking to rent access to virtual machines for testing of our online services from areas of the world other than North America. Specifically: Australia, Europe, Japan, South America, and wherever else. I'd love to get some recommendations of companies which offer these services. One I'm looking at in the UK is a company called "1&1 Hosting".

They do not have to be Windows VM's but Windows would be preferred as they would allow us to run a larger range of tests.

Thanks for your answers!

Edit1: the VM does not need a static IP nor does it need an included domain name, that is to say these are not requirements.

Comment: What sort of tests are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out [Anchor](http://anchor.com.au) for hosting a VPS in AU.

Answer (score 3):

For Europe [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) is what you're looking for. There's an option to create a Windows virtual machine in Europe for $0.13 per hour. Create one, run your test, destroy it. Pay only for what you use.